# Debug friendly alternative to NetworkManager?

Tags: wifi, network-interface, networkmanager

NetworkManager is great, when it works. When it fails I find it completely impossible to debug.

Is there an alternative that is similarly easy to use, but which also shows you what is being run, so you can manually run this and possibly fix it, if it does not work?

**Background**

I am currently at a hotel where the wifi works great in the hallway, but is gone in the rooms; the rooms must be faraday cages - at least for the wifi frequencies.

I have an external USB stick and a USB extension chord for the same reason, so I can simply attach that and get connection by sticking the USB-wifi out the door. This has worked great for years, but no longer works, and I get no feedback from NetworkManager on why it does not.

A perfect alternative would include a way to select one interface as the internet connection and select multiple other interfaces as sharing interfaces (USB, Bluetooth, wifi, ethernet).

Comment: I always ran into trouble with network manager, too, so I've disabled it, and manage WLAN with `wpa_cli` and the wpa-supplicant config file, and other network adapters the old-fashioned way. But it seems you are looking for something more high level, but not as buggy as network manager, so I don't really know what to recommend ...

Comment: I usually do not install both it and resolvconf. Have a look at what the FreeBSD/OpenBSD guys are using for wifi.